# VBA to Capture text between Tags

Tags: javascript, dom, excel, web-scraping, vba

I am trying to extract data from a website using VBA in excel. 
The page source has the following (below), and I can extract the text "This is my text" which is between the "A" tags, and I can extract everything that is between the "DIV" tags, which displays as " This is my text (XXXXX)" .....but I am unable to extract the block of text that just appears after the "/A"...eg "(XXXXX)"

```
 <div style="padding: 1px;"><a href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('MainPage'),{'j_id32'},'');}return false">This is my text</a> (XXXXX)</div>

<div style="padding: 1px; padding-left:20px;"><a href="#" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('MainPage'),{'j_id32'},'');}return false">This is my text</a> (XXXXXXXX)</DIV>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: You may want to look into this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393236/reading-web-pages-using-excel-vba/7413486#7413486), and once you have identified the DOM object of interest, read out its innerHTML property.

Comment: The innerHTML property just seems to return the entire HTML string (As displayed in my original question), which is substantially more than what the innertext property returns. What i need to do is return part of the innertext string, a part that appears outside the A-TAGS but INSIDE the DIV-TAGS.

Comment: If you know that the string you want is the one after the last tag closing inside your DIV element, use `= Right(OBJ.innerHTML, Len(OBJ.innerHTML) - InStrRev(OBJ.innerHTML, ">"))` whereby OBJ is your DIV element

Comment: Thanks @MikeD. That works a charm. Didn't think to use that!!

Comment: pleasure ... I will convert this to a real answer then ...

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the string you want is the one after the last tag closing inside your DIV element, use

```
TXT = Right(OBJ.innerHTML, Len(OBJ.innerHTML) - InStrRev(OBJ.innerHTML, ">"))
```

whereby OBJ is your DIV element