# Submitting value from a excel row to a webpage and get return value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet with a list of users, is there a way i could send this list one by one to a internal website which accepts the user name in a text box to check if this user exist and print the output to a new column ?

When the user is found it will print the user details.
When not found it will tell not found.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393236/reading-web-pages-using-excel-vba/7413486#7413486 ... for a head start ... in particular the commented get... and set... statements should be of use for you

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with something similar to this:

```
Function testHttpGet()
    Dim oHttp As Object
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    MyUrl = "http://10.0.21.130/test.php?name=mikeqq"
    oHttp.Open "GET", MyUrl, False
    oHttp.send
    'MsgBox oHttp.Status
    If oHttpPost.Status < 300 Then
        SomeVar = oHttpPost.responseText
        MsgBox SomeVar
    End If
End Function
```