# VBA String pattern PinPointing

Tags: vba, excel

Ok so i have these 6 which are coerced during Running-time as String Values. So these lines below are String values

```
bdx-20131231.xml
bdx-20131231.xsd
bdx-20131231_cal.xml
bdx-20131231_def.xml
bdx-20131231_lab.xml
bdx-20131231_pre.xml
```

inside a macro we have a small simple loop that iterates and prints on the immediate window the string values that end with ".xml" so the xsd (second one) is not printed by the loop. Following you can see the loop

```
For Each el In IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")
            If el.href Like "*.xml" Then
                Debug.Print el.innertext, el.href
            End If
next el
```

So we are left with these

```
bdx-20131231.xml
bdx-20131231_cal.xml
bdx-20131231_def.xml
bdx-20131231_lab.xml
bdx-20131231_pre.xml
```

However what i am trying to nail here is the `XBRL INSTANCE DOCUMENT` which has no letters at the end of it's naming it's bdx- `numbers_only` so **it's the first one that interests us only.**

However the statement... `Like "*.xml"` grabs and prints both 5 in the immediate window.

---

The first thing that came to my mind is ok split in two the `bdx-20131231.xml` and use the function `IsNumeric` on the second part after the hyphen however ***the value is coerced.***

How can we make the loop pick only the first one `bdx-20131231.xml`?

---

For reasons of completeness you can see the whole code which the loop comes from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787036/vba-href-crawl-on-browsers-source-code/21862387#21862387)

Courtesy of [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work:

```
Like "*[0-9].xml"
```

Comment: Checking positive in 5 according to rules

Comment: Glad I was able to help. :-)