# VBA Remove a part of the code and put him into a separate procedure

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2010

I have absolutely no idea how to create separate `subs`/`functions` to shorten the `code`. I am referring to those *subs(something as integer, etc)*

Below we have this `code` that resides in my core `module`

```
Set els = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    For Each el In els
        If Trim(el.innertext) = "Documents" Then
            colDocLinks.Add el.href
        End If
    Next el

    For Each XML_link In colDocLinks
        LoadPage IE, CStr(XML_link)
        For Each el In IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a")
            If el.href Like "*[0-9].xml" Then
                With Worksheets("CONTROL_ROOM").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .NumberFormat = "@"
                    .Value = Ticker
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = el.href
                End With
                Debug.Print el.innertext, el.href
                colXMLPaths.Add el.href
            End If
        Next el
    Next XML_link
```

I really need to shorten my `code`. How could i create a separate `sub` or `function` instead of having this chunk of `code` into my main `module`?

*Books offer over-simplistic examples and have not been any help to me in real situations* like this one. Do i need to make declarations such as `Dim els` inside the separate `Sub` or `Function`? Thank you for your patience in advance.

And most importantly no-matter how much time i look to these examples i cannot figure out which variables i put in here:

```
(Private) Sub / (Private) Function ( variables ?)
```

+++Any good examples/links will help.

Comment: You are free to never declare any variables (or to declare only some) but that's the road to buggy code. `Option Explicit` should be at the top of every module. If there are variables which you only use in a specific Sub or Function, then that's where they should be declared.  You do not need to declare any variables passed in as parameters to your Sub/Function. Typically you use a function if you want to return a variable, and a Sub if you do not.

Comment: Try this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/index.html this should be a great start for you to learn the language.

Comment: Thanks Guys (@TimWilliams this is your code that i found in an OS answer) how many where the odds of that?

Comment: @TimWilliams http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891468/vba-procedure-outputs-a-varying-number-of-string-variables-to-be-declared-and-re that's the one!!!

Comment: Odds are quite high actually ;-)  I thought those lines looked familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subroutine anytime you want to be able to call a block of code to do something, without returning any kind of value to the code that called it:

> Sub MainCode()
>
> ```
> Dim myString as String
>
> ...'all your main code
>
> Call OtherSub(myString)
>
> ...'all your main code
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> Sub OtherSub(theString as String)
>
> ```
> 'Do Something with the string theString
> ```
>
> End Sub

Create a function when you want to return something:

> Sub MainCode()
>
> ```
>  Dim myString as String, newString as String
>
> ...'all your main code
>
> NewString = OtherSub(myString)
>
> ...'all your main code
> ```
>
> End Sub
>
> Function ManipulateString(theString as String)
>
> ```
> 'Do Something with the string theString
>
>  ManipulateString = theString & ...
> ```
>
> End Function

At the end of the function, to return the new value, simply set the function name equal to whatever you are passing back.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you man i can make my own Functions and SubRoutines now~