# Need Excel Macro for Updating stock

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update stock using excel macro, My question is if I put hyperlink into the Cell 1, macro should retrieve the specific data from that webpage e.g. SKU AND STOCK I have never used macros before so I have no idea how to code this. If anyone help me in this case i would be very thankful.

COLUMN A (http://www.etradehouse.com/search.aspx?find=56K-PCI) COLUMN B, C SHOULD HAVE RETRIEVED DATA (SKU AND STOCK)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from general VBA coding techniques (syntax, Excel object model, etc.) you should familiarize yourself with

- how to access HTML pages using a VBA browser object
- how to search, find and move through a DOM object
- how to read out content from a HTML element

resources: [Reading Web Pages using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393236/reading-web-pages-using-excel-vba/7413486#7413486)