# How to grab links from source code with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so any help would be appreciated.

I would like to collect all of the search result links from this website within the source code:

http://ingatlan.com/lista/elado+telek+budaors

It is in the source as : 
href="/budaors/elado+telek/egyeb-telek/pest+megye+budaors+sovirag+utca+8-10/21503632

However it is not linked to any table.

Thanks:
Attila

Comment: please show us what you have tried to accomplish your task, then we can help tweak your code to get it working, if it's not working ... That said, there are few pages on this link that should help you: http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/excel-vba/automate-internet-explorer/

Comment: maybe this answer will help you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393236/reading-web-pages-using-excel-vba/7413486#7413486

Comment: hint: you want to look into the children of a table element with `class="search-results"`

Answer (score 0):

I have the below script to download the  data from a specific link:

Sub Adott_hirdetes_adatai()

```
    Dim IE As Object: Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For X = 1 To 1
    Application.StatusBar = X

    IE.Navigate "http://ingatlan.com/budaors-torokugrato/elado+telek        /lakoovezeti-telek/pest+megye+budaors/21284950"

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.ReadyState = 4
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
    Loop

    'Hirdetés azonosítója
     BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 1) = "Hirdetés azonosítója"
     BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 1) = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("adid")(0).innertext
     'Hirdetés fejléce
      BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 2) = "Hirdetés neve"
      BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 2) = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("pageTitle")(0).innertext
```

'ár
          BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 3) = "Ár"
          BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 3) = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("importantInformations four-column-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext
           'Terület
          BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 4) = "Terület"
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 4) = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("importantInformations four-column-table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
           'A "Típus" szó kiíratása
            BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 5) = "Típus"
            BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 5) = IE.Document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext
           ' A "Gáz" szó kiíratása
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 6) = "Gáz"
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 6) = IE.Document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
           'A "villany" szó kiíratása
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 7) = "Villany"
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 7) = IE.Document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext
          'A "Csatorna" szó kiíratása
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 8) = "Csatorna"
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 8) =              IE.Document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
          'A "víz" szó kiíratása
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 9) = "Víz"
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 9) = IE.Document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(2).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innertext
          'A "kilátás" szó kiíratása
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 10) = "Kilátás"
           BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 10) = IE.Document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tr")(2).getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innertext
           'A hirdetés szövege
            BazsiSheet.Cells(X, 11) = "Komment"
            BazsiSheet.Cells(X + 1, 11) = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("box-section comment")(0).innertext

```
        Next X

        Set IE = Nothing

        Application.StatusBar = ""
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        End Sub
```

Which works fine, but I still could not collect the links from the search result.

Thanks:
Attila